# Remove element from nested map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have map structure

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> outerMap= getMap();

for (int count = 0; count < outerMap.size(); count++) {
Map<String, String> innerMap = outerMap.get(count);

String tempValue = innerMap.get("tempKey");
innerMap.remove("tempKey");
someOperations(tempValue);
}
```

When i remove it at first iteration from inner map it removes that key and value pair from other maps but that is not what i want. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am guessing that `get(i)` always returns same map. How do you create this map exactly? Post `getMap()` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are building your maps the wrong way.

When the first call to innerMap.remove() actually affects the innerMap you are using within the second iteration, then there is only one explanation: that **innerMap** must be the **same** object.

So I guess, when you build your maps, you do something like:

```
Map<String, String> mapLaterUsedAsInner = new ...
mapLaterUsedAsInner.put ... gets filled
```

And then you have something like

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> outerMap = new ...
for (int i=0; i< ...) {
  outterMap.put(i, mapLaterUsedAsInner);
```

So the point is: if you want that your "inner maps" are all **independent** of each other, then they **must** be independent objects. If they aren't ... then the first modification affects them "all" ("all" being actually just **one** object)!

So, the solution could be as easy as:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,String>> outerMap = new ...
for (int i=0; i< ...) {
  outterMap.put(i, new HashMap<>(mapLaterUsedAsInner));
```

as that would create individual **copies** per counter.

Comment: Glad to hear that. So, if that "answered" your question, feel free to accept my answer.